# How I can I get my grid to appear from a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, grid, datepicker

I have a grid of buttons in my code where the user clicks on the word "click here" and the grid of buttons would be displayed. This uses jquery, what I want to know is that does anyone know a way so that the user can click on a text box and what happens is that the grid of buttons appear and if the user clicks on a button or clicks away from the grid, the grid disappear again. In other words I want it to work exactly how the Jquery datepicker works (to see the datepciker jquery please click [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

To see my code then it is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QmLmC/24/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**UPDATED**

```
$('#showGrid').click(function(e) {
    if ($('#gridone').css("display") == "table") {
        $('#gridone').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#gridone').css("display", "table");
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").click(function() {
    $('#gridone').hide();   
});

$('#gridone  input').click(function(){
    $('.box INPUT').val($('.box INPUT').val() + $(this).val() );
    $('#gridone').hide();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/QmLmC/26/)

Comment: Hi, that looks very good.Just one question, If I change "click here" into a text box, then if I click on a button, will the value of the button be displayed in the text box, coz in your example if I click on a button, it replaces click here with the button.

Comment: I left your code as it was in your original example. I've updated the answer and fiddle with the functionality you mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, just one lat question (this is definetly last question), you are 90% there, the only things is that if I click on a button (lets say "P"), it is displayed in the text box, but lets say I change my mind and I click on button "C", then in the text box it displays P and C. So how can you do it so that if I click on a button, the value of that button replaces the previous value in the text box?

Comment: Just change this line: `$('.box INPUT').val($(this).val());`

Comment: thank you that has worked brilliantly. This is easily going to be marked as best answer